# How can I access an object in one level deep file?

Tags: php, wordpress, require-once

In my header.php file, I wrote:

```
 <?php require_once('includes/session.php');?>
```

In my admin_login.php file I wrote:

```
 get_header(); 
 global $session;
 $session->login($found_user);
```

`get_header()` will include `header.php` which has `'session'` class by
 `<?php require_once('includes/session.php');?>`

and admin_login.php has header.php by get_header().

So why session class is not available in my admin_login.php? It show the following error:

```
Call to a member function is_logged_in() on a non-object in 
D:\server\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\amrajegeachi.com\super_admin_home.php on line 9
```

all code inside admin_login.php:

```
<?php 
  /*
    Template Name: admin login form
  */
?>

<?php 
require_once('includes/user.php');
get_header(); // includes.session.php has been included by header.php

?> 
      <div id="super-admin-login">              
  <?php 
if(isset($_POST['login-btn']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['user']) || !empty($_POST['password']))
      {
          $username=$_POST['user'];
          $password=$_POST['password']; 
          $found_user = User::authenticate($username,$password);
          if($found_user){
              global $session;
               $session->login($found_user);   
          }  
      }
}
?>
  <form name="input" action="#" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr><td> Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="user" /></td> </tr>
      <tr><td> Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td> </tr>
      <tr><td> </td><td class="btn"> <input type="submit" name="login-btn" value="Login" /></td></tr>
    </table> 
</form>
      </div>       
   <?php  
    get_footer();
    ?>
```

Comment: How and when `$session` var is initialized?

Comment: $session  is initialized at session.php

Comment: Sure, but how exactly? Also, is `global $session` used within the function or in the global scope? If latter, it's a bit meaningless; you'd at least define it _before_ calling `get_header()`.

Comment: I have added code in my original question. and in short session.php is as follows:
class Session{
// member function declaration goes here
}
$session = new Session();
$message = $session->message();

Comment: What happens when you write `global $session = new Session();` instead? Looks like the file is included in the scope of function, hence the problem.

Comment: The error states it's in `super_admin_home.php`, could you please post the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this error.I changed getheader() to require_once("header.php"); Now it works fine